# MySQL 5.6 - Full-text search in a AES column

Tags: mysql, select, encryption, full-text-search, aes

I got a new job and I have started to work in a web app since this week. This project works with some kind of AES-Encryption in some columns. And I've been asked to create a "full-text search" using data from some of the table which has the AES-columns. However, I can not make it work. I've tried this until this moment

### Query

```
SELECT AES_DECRYPT(customer_name,'j?YlTr_[Uh>/m2x-Zc*t[i=M$L6atX#>W|}DAZ-$f:Fj$[D+!:SLJhf+NWN#3_&'), 
MATCH (customer_name) AGAINST ('Fernando' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS customer
FROM customer
WHERE MATCH (customer_name) AGAINST ('Fernando' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

But this seems not to work. I must add that I'm using a full-text index in 'customer_name' although I found that it's not a good idea to do that. I dont know if my solution is the best. What would you do in this case, considering that the app must keep the encryption storage but also it must allow search?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've got a problem here. You can't use a full text index on a computed column like AES_DECRYPT(customer_name), because MySQL can't do this. Full text search against the encrypted content can't work either. You may look into the abilities of external search engines like lucene for your goal.

Comment: Lucene? but it means I must use a third-party component, right?

Comment: Yes, why not? I don't even know if those will work at all. You've got two requirements that are antipodal of each other. I don't envy you but wish you luck.

Comment: This topic is extremely hard to handle. I'm still looking for some answers.